# RegEx for matching one to three words after a keyword

Tags: regex, pcre

I have syslog like:

```
Apr 22 11:52:44 localhost systemd: Stopped logstash. 
Apr 22 11:52:07 localhost systemd: Started Getty on tty1. 
Apr 22 11:52:07 localhost systemd: Started Hostname Service. 
Apr 22 11:52:07 localhost systemd: Started Import network configuration from initramfs.
```

I wanna get 3 words after status (short program name).

My solution:

```
"\bsystemd:\s+\S+\s\K\S+\s\S+\s\S+"
```

But, program name can be less than 3 words (like logstash in my log), thats why I need a regex to match 1 or 2 or 3 words depending on the length of the string.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `\bsystemd:\s+\S+\s\K\S+(?:\s\S+){0,2}`. If the words should start with an uppercase letter use `\bsystemd:\s+\S+\s\K[A-Z]\S*(?:\s[A-Z]\S*){0,2}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, just what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\bsystemd:\s+\S+\s\K\S+(?:\s\S+){0,2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8fZcWR/1).

The `\S+(?:\s\S+){0,2}` part does the job: it matches 1+ non-whitespace chars followed with 0 to 2 repetitions of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ non-whitespace chars.

See the regex graph:

[image]

[image]